# Proof of method to divide a circle in $N$ parts

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to prove the correctness of the following well-known method to divide a circle into N parts (figure from [here](http://www.drawinghowtodraw.com/drawing-lessons/improve-drawing/pr-drawing-bk/images/pr-drawing-bk_img_106.jpg)):

[image]

If I call $O$ as the center of the circle, $R$ to its radius and N to the number of divisions, I see that:

1. $\triangle AOC$ is a rectangle triangle, with $\angle OAC = 60^\circ$, $\angle AOC = 90^\circ$, and $\angle OCA = 30^\circ$. Furthermore, the length $|AC|=2R$ and the length $|AO|=R$.
2. In $\triangle AED$, the length $|AD|=4\cdot\dfrac RN$.
3. In $\triangle AEO$, $|EO|=|AO|=R$.

I want to prove that in $\triangle AEO$, $\angle AOE = \dfrac{2\pi}{N}$ and $\angle OEA = \angle OAE = \dfrac{\pi}{2N}(N - 2)$.

I do not see how to progress from this point.

(PS: doing it just for fun, remembering old times of technical draws)

Comment: "|AD|=4R/N" do you mean N = 7 here? If not, in the general case, you probably want |AD| = (N+1)R/2N.

Comment: It may be relevant that a [heptagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptagon) is not constructible by straightedge and compass.

Comment: @Bill: yes, N is the number of divisions (clarified now in the question), 7 in the example graph. The step 1 of construction method is divide the diameter in N parts at take two of them, thus |AD|=2*2*R/N=4R/N.

Comment: @BrianTung: sorry, I'm not able to use your clarification to progress/solve the issue.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Your construction is only an approximation, see for example [here](http://hptgn.tripod.com/heptagon.htm).

Comment: @dxiv: disappointing, this was one of my favorites from school age. I want my money back ! :-) Being more serious, also approximate for other N values ? Can we estimate the error ?

Comment: @pasabaporaqui: Many polygons are exactly constructible, though not necessarily by the algorithm presented here.  See the link in my answer for constructible polygon for more details.

Comment: If you are confident with Italian, at page 58 of [these notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwSWVCckk1cll3ZGM/view) you can find a discussion about the fact the such construction is just an approximated construction, and not an exact one. We have a similar situation for the $9$-gon: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonagon#Construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attempt to prove the construction correct is doomed to failure, because as it turns out, a [heptagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptagon) is not constructible by straightedge and compass alone.  More details can be found at the Wikipedia link.  See also [constructible polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon).

The construction is merely an approximation, albeit a pretty good one for a heptagon.  The actual angle produced by this method is about $51.52$ degrees; it should instead be $51\frac37$ degrees, which is an error of about one part in $600$ or so.  Good enough for most drawings, certainly, but not something I'd build to.  (The error is about two-thirds of a degree across the entire heptagon.)

Comment: Could you expand how to find the value 51.52 degrees you said ? I do not see it in the links you provide (still looking for)

Comment: @pasabaporaqui: I didn't include it (and it is not included in the web pages—sorry, I didn't mean to imply it was), because it's not mathematically interesting.  I simply computed the intersection of the line and the circle, and pushed the result into an inverse trigonometric function.